# Cannot accsess array of objects inside same class?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Ive got this kinda stupid exam question in which I'm told to make an array of objects IN MAIN method.
I defined the class `Account` with two variables - String owner and double amount.

Then I'm told to make the Account class handle change of values sum of all amounts. etc.
But I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong - I cannot get access to the array from `getAmount()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Account[] account = new Account[10];
    for ( int i=0; i<account.length; i++) 
    {
    account[i]=new Account();
    }
    account[0].owner = "Thomas";
    account[0].amount = 24325;
    System.out.println(getAmount(0)); //<- dont work,  but works with account[0].amount
}

public static double getAmount(int x) 
{
    double s = account[x].amount;   //<<------- CANNOT FIND SYMBOL
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`account` is local to the main method, so it can't be accessed from other methods unless passed to them as a parameter.

An alternative is to declare it as a static member:

```
static Account[] account = new Account[10];

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for ( int i=0; i<account.length; i++) 
    {
        account[i]=new Account();
    }
    account[0].owner = "Thomas";
    account[0].amount = 24325;
    System.out.println(getAmount(0));
}
```

Comment: thing is that i'm told to make the array in the main method.

Comment: @ThomasWegener You can still initialize it in the main method, but you must declare it outside in order to access it from a different method. If you want to keep it local to main, `getAmount` can accept the array as a parameter - `getAmount(account,0)`

Answer (score 1):

In this case account is a local variable for main, if you want to use the method getAmount you have two options:
-Declare the array as static and put it out of the main method (the array would be a global variable)
-Pass the array as a parameter in getAmount.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Account[] account = new Account[10];
    for ( int i=0; i<account.length; i++) 
    {
    account[i]=new Account();
    }
    account[0].owner = "Thomas";
    account[0].amount = 24325;
    System.out.println(getAmount(0), account); //<- dont work,  but works with account[0].amount
}
public static double getAmount(int x, Account[] account) 
{
    double s = account[x].amount;   //<<------- CANNOT FIND SYMBOL
    return s;
}
```